# What is the intuitive reason why $\sigma$-finite measures are so important?

Tags: measure-theory

I have recently started studying the more measure theory side of probability, and a condition that comes up constantly is that a measure in question is $\sigma$-finite.

My textbook defines a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $S$ as being a measure such that there exists sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$ where

1. $\cup_i A_i = S$
2. $\mu (A_i) < \infty $ for all $i$

I don't understand why this definition in particular is used so often. What is it about being able to find such a subsequence that is so important?

I'm hoping someone can either give me a simple intuitive explanation, or maybe an example of how them not being $\sigma$-finite can cause problems

Comment: I’ll try to write a fuller answer when I have more time but: one reason is that it turns out many results that we have for finite measures (e.g. Radon-Nikodym) generalise relatively straightforwardly to $\sigma$-finite measures, whereas the extension to general measures is not quite so easy (or is not even true!). So in some sense you can think of a $\sigma$-finite measure space in the same way as a finite measure space without losing very much.

Answer (score 2):

It's the next best thing to having a space of finite measure.

It means you can build the space up out of chunks of finite measure.

It doesn't get you anything to have a finite union of such chunks (that's always true), so the next best thing is the "smallest" infinite union -- i.e., a countably infinite union.

For example, $\mathbb R$ doesn't have finite Lebesgue measure, but every interval $(a,b)$ does, and $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of such intervals.